# Bad bit in file

Tags: linux, files, memory, hard-disk, inode

I have an image that I know was ok. (`image.jpg`)

A few days later when I open, `image.jpg` was corrupt. (not displaying properly)

**How to check if bit in hard disk drive where image is located is failing?**

I am ok with permanent destruction of image.

Can I `dd` over file with all ones wait a few days and check if any of the bits have flipped?

If it matters, I am on standard Ubuntu installation.

Comment: What type of file system are you on? Most have an fsck like facility to discover and possibly correct such things. Crc can also be used, if you save crc info of correct file in advance

Comment: Filesystem: `ext4`

Comment: Please add that info to the question and try to run fsck on the volume

Comment: I only want to check the HDD where the image file is and not the *whole* HDD

Comment: If you have any suspicion of a corrupt drive, I would recommend checking the entire drive.

Comment: Look at the SMART values of your harddisk (`smartctl`). Besides the harddisk failing, some faulty program may also have overwritten some part of the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `badblocks`, which seems to work on regular files provided the files aren't open:

```
badblocks -b 512 -vn image.jpg
```

Example on a real *13K* file:

```
sudo badblocks -b 512 -vn \
               /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mwe/example-image.jpg
```

Output:

```
Checking for bad blocks in non-destructive read-write mode
From block 0 to 25
Testing with random pattern: Pass completed, 0 bad blocks found. (0/0/0 errors)
```